# subtract date from another column which is not a date in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to subtract a date column from another column which is not a date. Generally, I would use

`select date - interval '3' month from table_name`

This would then give me the date 3 months before the date column but this time around I want the '3' to come from a column within the same table. This column would have different numbers say 3, 4 etc.

I have tried a couple of methods using concatenation but it has not worked. (This is an Oracle SQL developer query)

Edit: Example - I have two columns, one column is a date format and the other is number format with numbers such as 1, 2, 3 and so on. I want to take the date in column 1 for example, 01/Jan/2024 and use column 2 to subtract the months from the date. For example, where the number is 1, the output should return 01/DEC/2023, where it is 2, output should return 01/Nov/2023  and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ADD_MONTHS`:

```sql
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(date_column, -number_of_months_column)
FROM   table_name;
```

*Note: for adding/subtracting months, use the `ADD_MONTHS` function rather than an `INTERVAL` literal as `ADD_MONTHS` will handle cases such as `ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2024-01-31', 1)` where there is no 31st February while `DATE '2024-01-31' + INTERVAL '1' MONTH` would fail.*

If your date always occurs in every month then you can multiply by a fixed interval:

```sql
SELECT date_column - number_of_months_column * INTERVAL '1' MONTH
FROM   table_name;
```

If you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, date_column, number_of_months_column) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2024-01-01', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2024-03-31', 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Then using `ADD_MONTHS` outputs:

| ADD_MONTHS(DATE_COLUMN,-NUMBER_OF_MONTHS_COLUMN) |
| --- |
| 2023-10-01 00:00:00 |
| 2024-02-29 00:00:00 |

Using an `INTERVAL` outputs the same for the first row but for the second row would give the exception:

```
ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rojKi60n)

Comment: the solution would not work because the other column has numbers such as 1, 3 , 4 rather than a date in string format. Column 1 is a date and column 2 has numbers such as 1, 2, 3 and so on. I want the numbers to subtract months from date. For example, if date is 01/JAN/2023 (date column), I want to substract 3 months from 01/JAN/2023 to get 01/October/2022

Comment: @Yusuf still use `ADD_MONTHS` and pass the `number_of_months` column to the second argument.

Comment: thanks, this works. And thanks on the  comment about usage of interval. I will ensure to modify my codes on that issue.